# Use temporary table in a separate query

Tags: r

I run one query and save the result in a data table in R. Then I run another query which includes the inner join command. I want to use the first data.table as the first table of the inner join of the second query and the second table is from a database. How can I do this?

I already tried to do it using DBI and data.table packages in R, but when i run this command:

```
TMEMPTPOL <- 
dbSendQuery(conCompass, 
paste0("select case when m.chgeffdt > getdate() then 'F' else 'C' end, m.CLNTCODE, m.POLNO, CERTNO, m.clntcode + 'Cert' + certno + 'Dep01', PRODCODE, BENPLNCD, COVGCODE, m.INIEFFDT, m.CHGEFFDT, m.RCDUSRID, getdate(),
          PRDSTATUS, isnull(PROLFIA,0), isnull(INFLFIA,0), isnull(NELAMT,0), m.CHGEFFDATE, m.polno+certno+prodcode+benplncd+covgcode+convert(char(8),m.chgeffdt,112)+'C' 
          from #param p (nolock) inner join TMEMPTpOL m with (nolock) on p.clntcode=m.clntcode and p.rcdsts='A'and m.INIEFFDT<= '", EffectiveDate,"' and m.chgeffdt<='", AsOfDate,"'"))
```

I get the error that object param is not found. (Param is the first data table which includes data from another query). How do i do this?

Comment: If the remote database had access to a local R environment to be able to join data to it, there would be _significant_ alarms going off about security breaches (not to mention the database now speaking "R", which is not a common thing). In general, if you want to inner join a SQL table with something, that something must be in that SQL database. I suggest you modify your previous query/statement to save its results into a temporary table _on the remote database_ and then inner join on it. After that, you can retrieve data to your R instance.

Comment: Side note: You may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries).

Comment: Most people need just a few functions from the `DBI` package: `dbConnect`, `dbGetQuery`, and `dbDisconnect` (though many just ignore this last one, since garbage-collection will eventually close the connection). Sometimes we may need `dbExecute`. There are ancillary uses for `dbListFields` and similar schema-functions. `dbBind` is also useful when repeating queries with different parameters, though hardly required. Few users should be using `dbSendQuery` (and the required `dbFetch` and `dbClearResult` afterwards) for retrieving data.

Comment: (My last comment is supposed to indicate that I suggest you use `dbGetQuery` instead of `dbSendQuery`.)